Manhwa(?) where a girl gets a second chance and tries to become Queen (?). She ends up maturing due to the fact she's experienced death and abuse
Sorry for any spelling mistakes, but the story starts out with a girl being mistreated by her family and her sister keeps framing her. She ends up dying some way (I forgot) but she comes back (same age) with a guide, kinda like a video game thing. Her family wants her to marry a gross guy so her sister doesn't have to do it, but she plans it out and leaves her family. After all that, she goes exploring. I can't remember anything else except that she comes across a guy who gets obsessed with her and her finding treasure, but she has red hair green eyes.
Please help me find this manhwa.

Hi, welcome to the site. While editing this post, I had make some guesses as to what you actually meant at certain points. Please review my edits, and if I made any mistakes, edit the question yourself to correct them. Thanks.

Also, can you be a bit clearer about what you meant by "a guide, kinda like a video game thing"?

This question also mentions a guide(book) - is it the same story? There's no answer, but it might include other details or help jog your memory.

The guide was an inventory that gave her points and that gave hints of what people were feeling.
